# evaluate integral using beta function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, beta-function

I am using substitution to evaluate the following integral using definition of beta function
$$ 
\int_0^{\infty} [1-(1-\epsilon) e^{- \mu z}]^n  \mu (1-\epsilon) e^{- \mu z} e^{\theta z} dz
$$
if I use the substitution $y=(1-\epsilon) e^{- \mu z}$ , then $z=-\frac{ \log \frac {y} {1-\epsilon}} {\mu}$ and the integral becomes
$$
\int_0^{1-\epsilon} [1-y]^n  \left[\frac {y}{1-\epsilon} \right]^{1-\theta /\mu} dz
$$
how can I get rid of $1-\epsilon$ in the upper limit integral using substitution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The incomplete Beta function is defined
$$
B(z;a,b)=\int_0^z u^{a-1}(1-u)^{b-1}du
$$
therefore your integral is
$$
B(1-\epsilon;2-\frac{\theta}{\mu},n+1)
$$
If $\epsilon=0$ you have the normal Beta function composed of Gamma functions,
$$
\frac{\Gamma (2-\frac{\theta}{\mu})\Gamma (n+1)}{\Gamma (3 +n-\frac{\theta}{\mu})}
$$
To approximate the integral you can expand the incomplete Beta functions in powers of $(1-\epsilon)$
$$
B(1-\epsilon;2-\frac{\theta}{\mu},n+1)=(1-\epsilon)^{2-\frac{\theta}{\mu}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\frac{\theta}{\mu}-1)_k}{k!(n+k+1)}(1-\epsilon)^k
$$where $(x)_k$ is the Pochhammer symbol.

Comment: Ok great. Thank you! I forgot about the incomplete beta function. Another thing, can I asymptotically approximate incomplete beta function $B(2-\epsilon; 2- \frac {\theta} {\mu}, n+1)\approx (1-\epsilon)^{2-\frac {\theta} {\mu}} \frac {(\frac {\theta}{\mu})_0} {n+1}$